# How do I create a new record for each column?

Tags: google-sheets

I'd love some help here. I have a table in google sheets with a bunch of columns and I'd like to create a new record for each column which has a value of 1. In the picture I've attached you can see what I mean. I have a table that looks like the one at the top in blue and I'd like to transform it to look like the one on the bottom in red. I want to do this transformation so I can get a join key for something I'm doing in Google Data Studio. Thanks in advance for the help!

Also, what are the proper terms for what I'm trying to do, what could I have googled instead to find the answer?

[I want to convert the table outlined in blue to look like the table outlined in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNllg.png)

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308944?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{A1, "Item #"}; 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:F4=1, A2:A4&"×"&B1:F1, )), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", )})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works beautifully